# Do I need to add mediaqueries for every width range?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm reading some books and trying to create a responsive layout but still don't know how to cope with random windows sizes. I know there's a difference between devices and screen, I just can't figure out why can't control display when resizing the browser window.

It that a structure issue, wrong css code or I'm forgetting something?! I need to add mediaqueries for variable widths ranges?

An example:
I set most sizes for devices (1204px, 768px, etc) works ok, but variable widths seems to act strange. I added then a mediaqueries such `@media screen and (max-width: 1100px){ ... }` but still I get issues on 720px or 620px etc.

I use display snipets [from here](http://nmsdvid.com/snippets/).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You might want to read this http://www.designbyfront.com/workinprogress/article/the-goldilocks-approach-to-responsive-design You probably don't need more media queries, but less and not `px`-based, but `em`-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me, I just found out that my code was messed: I had mediaqueries on wrong order so classes end up being ignored. Please refer to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790321/why-do-the-order-of-media-queries-matter-in-css).

Thanks you all!