# @media queries not applying some styles

Tags: css, media-queries

I have the following media query which applies the background style to the body successfully, however it does not change the others, any ideas pleople?

```
@media (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
body {
    background:#F00;
}
.contentsearch.navbar {
    margin-left: -475px !important;
    top: 200px !important;
    width: 950px !important;
}
.contentTabs {
    margin-left: -475px !important;
    width: 948px !important;
}
.ui-tabs-panel { 
    width: 948px !important;
}
}
```

heres the original css for these elements

```
.contentsearch.navbar { 
     position:absolute; 
     top:200px; 
     width:1170px; 
     left:50%; 
     margin-left:-585px;  
}
.contentTabs {  
border-bottom: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    border-left: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    border-right: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    bottom: 55px;
    height: auto !important;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -585px;
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 241px;
    width: 1168px;
 }
.ui-tabs-panel {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD !important;
    border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC !important;
    bottom: -1px !important;
    height: auto !important;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 47px !important;
    width: 1168px;
}
```

Comment: In what order do these styles get applied?  The media queries need to come after your initial CSS declarations

Comment: A fiddle replicating the problem would help.

Comment: @andymacd Care to link something that prove your claim? Because last I checked it can be before or after. media got priority over any other CSS when the media condition are met.

Comment: [here you are](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790321/why-do-the-order-of-media-queries-matter-in-css)

Comment: And http://jsfiddle.net/KuHQR proving @andymacd right.

Comment: @andymacd i have tried placing them right at the end of everything and till no result

Comment: @andymacd alright thank you. Rereading my older projects I thought I had media before my initial declaration. Which is why I wasn't sure about that.

Comment: @Tom [check out this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vkY5K/) - I used your css but I am not sure of the HTML, it works here.

Answer (score 4):

Try with this :

```
    @media all and (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1200px){
....
}
```

You forgot declared on what type of screen you want it to be active
@media **all** and.....

You have :

- all
- screen
- print
- handheld
- tv
- etc..

[You have excellent article for this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Comment: I was gonna answer but you were faster then me. :) +1 to you

Answer (score 0):

Without media type it works anyway.

If you resize browser nothing happens? 
Original css should be displayed when your screen size has more than 980px, correct?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue, thanks for your responses.

The problem was i was copy and pasting styles from another application, in transit them seem to have picked up some kind of strange formatting/characters, after rewriting them by hand it now works!