# media filter css issues

Tags: html, css

I have the following css:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .directory-container {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .directory-container .banner-description {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #main-site h1 {
        left: 20%; 
    }

    #insta-shop-grid .profile-user .user-bio {
         left: 20%; 
    }

    .banner-title {
        margin-top: -20px;
    }

    #main.products .filter {
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
}
```

I've resized my screen to 1024 and the .banner-title is applied correctly. However why is it that the `main.products .filter` not applied?

Full site can be seen [here](http://directory.shopious.com/). Just resize the window to width 1024.

Comment: I see no `#main.products .filter` rules within a media selection block. Are you sure you've uploaded the right CSS file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule that's apparently being matched (according to Firebug) is

```
@media="screen"
#main.products .filter {
    margin: 5px 30px;
}
```

You've got a bunch of different .css files -- this rule is in `3a76827_part_6_product-and-profile_11.css`.  I'm not sure where the rule that you expect to be applied is located at, but I bet it's in a CSS file that loads before this one.  Here's why:

To understand what's going on, you need to understand how @media queries are applied.  Given that the CSS rule is the same between two media queries, the last media query will be the one that gets applied.  So if your `@media screen and (max-width: 1024px)` rule loads before your `@media screen` rule, the latter rule will apply.

See here for a similar question: [Why does the order of media queries matter in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790321/why-do-the-order-of-media-queries-matter-in-css)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting !important.

```
#main.products .filter {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

or use this instead:

```
#insta-shop-filter .filter {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```