# Issue with Mobile landscape vs Tablet portrait

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have written CSS media query for mobile landscape and tablet portrait. Here they are

For mobile landscape

```
@media (min-width : 480px) and (max-width : 800px) {
...
}
```

For tablet portrait

```
@media (min-width : 533px) and (max-width : 800px) {
...
}
```

When I open it in Mobile landscape view both queries have got triggered (mobile landscape & tablet portrait). Mobile landscape view is being used tablet portrait css media query since both condition are met. So I can see that both queries on the page.

Is there any way to force media to fetch mobile landscape code?

Thanks

Comment: change the order of your queries? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790321/why-do-the-order-of-media-queries-matter-in-css

Comment: Have you tried to use also `@media screen and (orientation:portrait)` and `landscape` ?

Comment: yes, i tried with 'orientation:portrait' it is working as expected.