# Mobile menu does not open

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got a menu that I want to hide/ show by changing it's top position.

Before I log in the menu looks like this:

```
<div class="lc">
    <h1><a href="./"><img src="logo.png" /></a></h1>
    <a href="#" id="menuBtn"></a>
    <nav id="mainNav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="....php">...</a></li>
            <li class="nav-li-..."><a href="....php">...</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

After I log in, some items are added:

```
<div class="lc">
    <h1><a href="./"><img src="logo.png" /></a></h1>
    <a href="#" id="menuBtn"></a>
    <nav id="mainNav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="....php">...</a></li>
            <li class="nav-li-..."><a href="....php">...</a></li>
            <li class="nav-li-..."><a href="....php">...</a></li>
            <li class="nav-li-..."><a href="....php">...</a></li>
            <li class="nav-li-..."><a href="....php">...</a></li>
            <li class="nav-li-..."><a href="....php">...</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="nav-admin">
            <strong>Administrator links:</strong><br />
            <a href="....php?users">...</a><br />
            <a href="....php?user_logs">...</a><br />
            <a href="....php?dealer_logs">...</a><br />
            <a href="....php?herd_logs">...</a><br />
            <a href="....php?php_logs">...</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

This CSS belongs to it:

```
.lc, nav, h1 {
    background: #fdf6bf;
    background: #FDD;
}
.lc {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 200;
    width: 14em;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding-top: .5em;
    overflow: auto;
}
    h1 {
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 1em;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: .5em;
    }
        h1 a {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
        }
            h1 a img { max-width: 70%; }

    nav ul { list-style: none; }
    nav ul li { padding: .75em 0 .75em 4.25em; }
    nav ul li.is-active { background: #fdf9dc; }
    nav ul li.is-active a:after {
        content: "\232A";
        position: absolute;
        right: .25em;
        top: -.05em;
        font-size: 3em;
        height: 1em;
        line-height: 1em;
        vertical-align: middle;
        color: #c9c49d;
    }

    nav ul a,
    .btn-add {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        height: 3em;
        padding-left: 1em;
        line-height: 3em;
        vertical-align: middle;
        font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #4f4e4c;
        font-size: 1em;
        font-weight: 600;
    }
        nav ul a:before,
        .btn-add:before {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            right: 100%;
            top: 50%;
            margin-top: -1.75em;
            width: 3.5em;
            height: 3.5em;
            background: url(images/menu_home.png) center center no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
        }

.nav-show { top: 0; }
.no-scroll { overflow: hidden; }

@media screen and (max-width: 550px) { 
    * { font-size: 1em; }
    nav {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 180;
        top: -100%;
        left: 0;
        padding-top: 4.5em;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
        background: #fffad5;
    }
    nav ul li.is-active { background: #fffcea; }

    .lc {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 3.5em;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

To trigger the menu I use

```
$(function() {
    $('#menuBtn').on('click', function(e) {
        $('body').toggleClass('no-scroll');
        $('#mainNav').toggleClass('nav-show');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

The problem is that the menu does show before the login. But after that, I am not able to open the menu. This problem isn't on the desktop PC, but only on mobile phones (Android). I've tried various phones and browser, but they all have the same issue.

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the Android browser handles fixed position differently that ie Firefox.

Especially a fixed div inside a fixed div.
The menu didn't show because `.lc` is only 3.5em high and got a hidden overflow. So by toggling an extra class to `.lc` to make it expand I solved the problem.

```
.lc-expand { max-height: 100%; }
```

```
$('#menuBtn').on('click', function(e) {
    $('body').toggleClass('no-scroll');
    $('.lc').toggleClass('lc-expand');
    $('#mainNav').toggleClass('nav-show');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add `.nav-show { top: 0; }` in `@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {` too ?

Since this `.nav-show { top: 0; }` is stated before the `@media`...
The `top:-100px` stays.

If found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8792163/2159528) to be sure of it.
It is well explained.

The problem is that your element gets `top: -100%` from `nav{` in the @media AND `top:0` from `.nav-show`. The last defined is used.
;)

Comment: Although you are right, this didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, 
Even position:fixed works, but you need to add some px to top (i.e around 70px), but this hides your additional links.

```
   @media screen and (max-width: 550px) { 
            * { font-size: 1em; }
            nav {
               position:relative;
                padding-top: 4.5em;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
               -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
                -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
                -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
                transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
                background: #fffad5;
            }
            nav ul li.is-active { background: #fffcea; }

            .lc {
                position: fixed;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;

            }
}
```

Comment: Changing it to a relative or absolute position makes no difference... thanks for the effort tho!

Comment: @LinkinTED could solve, if we work on working example, as fiddle doesn't show that php codes, can't solve much there.