# Media Query overriding other media query when it shouldn't be

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

Right now I am using a screen resolution of 3840x2160 and zoomed in at 250%, when I run `document.documentElement.clientHeight` it returns 713. So I wrote a media query to work with this, and that media query is `@media (max-height: 713px){...}` but that media query is getting overridden by this media query `@media (max-height: 754px){...}` and I have no idea why this is happening

Comment: When you're using two `max` media queries, they have to be placed from largest first down to the smallest.

Comment: Styles will apply for 754 and under, so if your rules are the same specificity and the 754 one comes after the 713 one, then it will override it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Media Queries overriding each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620499/media-queries-overriding-each-other)

Comment: Thanks for the answer everyone on the order of the media queries, my 754 was after my 713. I moved the 754 over my 713 and it worked. I've made a mental note on the answer

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the fact that your 754px media queries is declared after the 713px one is the problem ? In CSS, the last declaration always win (considering the selector is the same)

In order to see which CSS property is currently applied on an element, you can use your [browser developer tools](https://www.lifewire.com/get-inspect-element-tool-for-browser-756549)