# Media Queries Stuck

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am attempting to utilize media queries to hide or unhide a div in HTML:

```
<div class="hide-medium hide-large">Test</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 994px){
    .hide-large{
        display:none
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 993px){
    .hide-medium{
        display:none
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 601px){
    .hide-small{
        display:none
    }
}
```

The div hides properly when the browser is sized accordingly; however when the browser size hits 601px and lower the div still stays hidden.  What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

Media queries **cascade**. That is to say, at `601px` your `@media screen and (max-width: 601px)` media query would correctly take affect, but the `@media screen and (max-width: 993px)` media query will **also** take affect, as `601px` is smaller than `993px`. Thus, the element has **both** media queries applied. And because your element still has the `hide-medium` class at a 'small' width, it will still be hidden.

If you don't want this to happen, I'd recommend explicitly setting a `min-width` on your middle media-query as well:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 994px) {
  .hide-large {
    display: none
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 993px) and (min-width: 602px) {
  .hide-medium {
    display: none
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 601px) {
  .hide-small {
    display: none
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hide-medium hide-large">Test</div>
```

It's also important to note that media queries in the same stylesheet are applied top-to-bottom. If you have a 'lower down' media query that has a valid rule for the target element, it will overwrite any valid media queries which are 'higher up'. You can make use off **only** `min-width` (mobile-first) or `max-width` (desktop-first) queries in this regard (without mixing them). This is further explained **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43107445/only-last-link-of-css-taking-the-effect/43268162#43268162)**.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I may have answered to quickly.  Should I repost or edit the original question?