# why i have to write my media query at the end of my css.Is there any sequence to write media query from larger to smaller screen size?

Tags: html, css

I am very confuse with the media query because when ever i apply media query it does not work properly is there ant sequence to write it in CSS file?

```
@media max-width(767px)  {body{background:red;}  }
@media max-width(992px)  {body{background:blue;}  }
@media max-width(1200px)  {body{background:#fff;}  }
```

Is there any proper sequence to write it according to the screen size?Is the any difference if i write it like this?

```
@media max-width(1200px)  {body{background:#fff;}  }
@media max-width(992px)  {body{background:blue;}  }
@media max-width(767px)  {body{background:red;}  }
```

Comment: can you explain your media do not work at all or because the order ?

Comment: yes if i write my media at the beginning of my page it does not working should i use my media query at the end of my css ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the order of media queries matter in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790321/why-does-the-order-of-media-queries-matter-in-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write your media as below.

Learn here:https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

See here:https://jsfiddle.net/r60xs5j7/3/

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {body{background:#fff;}  }
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px)  {body{background:blue;}  }
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px)  {body{background:red;}  }
```

and whenever you put them in css they have to work(Except for a case of `override` that you will need use `!important`)

See here(end of css):https://jsfiddle.net/r60xs5j7/5/

**Note!**

You need this `meta` in `head` tag to make `media query` works:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: yeah no issues but can you please tell me that do you use media with max and min width ?

Comment: what is the right way to right it using max and min with or just only the width?

Comment: it for your decision.... you can lean better and deeper here:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176761/discussion-between-sumit-kumar-and--).