# "@media only screen and ()" css not overwriting

Tags: html, css, media-queries

[image: Inspected CSS]

It's an SVG (in img tag) thats held inside a div, for *some* reason the `@media only screen and ()` CSS wont overwrite the previous CSS rules. And i have **no clue** why this is, could someone please explain/give a solution?

Comment: Please share your code in text. Not a screenshot.

Comment: Quick fix: Add `!important` next to the properties or change the order of the queries

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the order of media queries matter in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790321/why-does-the-order-of-media-queries-matter-in-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screenshot also shows the lines of the stylesheet in which these rules are written: The regular rule is in line 131, the media query rule in line 63. According to this the regular rule is *after/below*  the media query, so it overwrites the media query, since it applies to everything. Just change the order in your stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! :)
This solved my problem, and i never knew the order mattered that much since i've never had this problem before (i always put "@media" first, then everything else).

Answer (score 2):

Your @media query is above the style you're trying to overwrite.

In CSS, if it's defined multiple times, the later/more specific one wins.