# Media query is not working to display page on other device screens properly

Tags: html, css

I went through all questions related to this title and applied many of the suggested solutions.The most informative ones were [link1](https://www.fixrunner.com/how-to-fix-media-query-not-working-in-wordpress/) [link2](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55721814/how-to-fix-responsive-design-issue-with-css). None of them worked. When I resize my browser I can not see the outer elements. I just want to be able to display my website on other devices screen properly. For example, when I halve the width of the browser screen, I can not see the other half of the website.

Here is my code pieces:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    #homepage {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 1920px;
            height: 4770px;
            background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
            overflow: hidden;
            --web-view-name: Ging Games- Home;
            --web-view-id: homepage;
            --web-scale-on-resize: true;
            --web-enable-deep-linking: true;
            
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 780px) {
      .homepage{
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        height: 4770px;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
        overflow: hidden;
        --web-view-name: Games- Home;
        --web-view-id: homepage;
        --web-scale-on-resize: true;
        --web-enable-deep-linking: true;
      }
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
      .homepage {
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        height: 4770px;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
        overflow: hidden;
        --web-view-name: Games- Home;
        --web-view-id: homepage;
        --web-scale-on-resize: true;
        --web-enable-deep-linking: true;
      }
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
      .homepage {
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        height: 4770px;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
        overflow: hidden;
        --web-view-name: Games- Home;
        --web-view-id: homepage;
        --web-scale-on-resize: true;
        --web-enable-deep-linking: true;
      }
    }

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
```

**From other StackOverflow solutions-suggestions I have already applied:**

- I used content="width=device-width at meta
- Media query order suggested starting bigger to a smaller size
- I used max-width, not the max-width-device as suggested
- Original homepage class is above the media query
- Gave reference to bootstrap
- My media query syntax is correct (many of the posts answers were related to space issues and not putting brackets or pixels etc.)

Additional information: I use [this website](https://www.000webhost.com/) to host my website.

Comment: Can we see your site or part which doesn't work??

Comment: @ch1puha what do you mean by which part?

Comment: You said "I can not see the **outer elements**." What is it??

Comment: what part is not working? I am very confused also you should add the other half of your code so it can be tested

Comment: @ParkerAucoin the whole code is too long (9690 loc). I only added the relevant parts.

Comment: Ok, do you have content inside the #homepage block?? Maybe problem in their css...

Comment: @ch1puha when I resize I expect to see the whole homepage in smaller screen size. However, all I can see is some portion of it on a smaller screen. I can not navigate to right to see the rest of the homepage. It looks like a screenshot of the top-left corner for instance.

Comment: @ch1puha yes I have elements(buttons, images, animations, texts) on the homepage. But I can not resize the whole elements one by one. The parent class is the homepage. I do my resizing in it.

Comment: @ch1puha the other elements are defined inside other classes, not inside the homepage block.

Comment: Do the #homepage has a parent container?? If yes, has it static `width`??

Comment: @ch1puha no, it doesn't have a parent.

Comment: 780px max-width is enough for phones and tablets but not for desktops

Comment: @hans-könig I test from here https://bluetree.ai/screenfly/ and none of the devices works. It looks like a zoomed screenshot inside a small screen.

Comment: Not really a surprise because the max-width for phones is 480px

Comment: I will post an answer and test it. Give me some minutes

Comment: @BB @media doesn't work, because you set `top` and `left` for blocks inside #homepage. More precisely, @media is working but elements has a specific `top` and `left` and they wouldn't change position

Comment: @ch1puha I am still trying to figure out, the thing is, aside from changing size, I tried to change an element colour with media query, nothing has changed. So, I believe media query is not recognized at all.

Comment: @BB can I see your code??

Comment: @ch1puha https://codeshare.io/5NDWA1 I shared the whole code via this link. Can you see it?

Comment: @ch1puha On top of what I tried above, I also have learned and tried to set the homepage position to "absolute" where the media position is "relative" according to a StackOverflow post. But it didn't work either.

Comment: Can't find any `@media` query

Comment: @ch1puha it is just below the "#homepage" class

Comment: @ch1puha I tried with less than 768px to see if that works. You can also search "768px" to find it.

Comment: @BB you should use `#homepage` instead `.homepage`

Comment: @ch1puha still didn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231284/discussion-between-b-b-and-ch1puha).

Answer (score 0):

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

 <style>
 #homepage {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1920px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);   
    }

 /* Ex. Large desktop */
 @media (min-width: 1280px){

   .homepage{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    }

 }

 /* Large desktop */
 @media (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1280px){

    .homepage{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    }

 }  

 /* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
 @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {

    .homepage{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    }

 }

 /* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
 @media (max-width: 767px) {

    .homepage{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    }

 }

 /* Landscape phones and down */
 @media (max-width: 480px) {

    .homepage{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
   }

 }  
 </style>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
```

Remember that for max-width 480px and 767px if you have a navbar class declare display = block(i.e. display:block; ) while the others should be none(i.e. display:none;)

Comment: I have just visited that link and the width is fine because there is no horizontal bar. This code is a skeleton.  You can put more code in there to fit your circumstance. That's now a home work for you

Comment: 'This code is a skeleton' this solution is already similar to mine, nothing is changed. Can you please elaborate on when and why to use 'display: none', I didn't get the idea?

Comment: If you provide us with more code you will get a precise solution

Comment: 'This solution is already similar to mine' - then you have to reframe your question

Comment: As I already stated I can not put the whole code since it is 9690 loc.

Comment: I found a way to share my code, here you can see https://codeshare.io/5NDWA1

Comment: Sorry that you placed all the codes in there. Normally just the relevant code is enough. I think the problem is that your other CSS stylings are not elastic. e.g. #Main_BackG(width: 1920px;). Using percentages will be better as that will fit too on mobile devices. No mobile phone will be happy when you say #Careers be at left: 960px; . I would prefer not to say top: 3655px; . In fact not declaring the top will ensure that the height is determined by size of content. So, just take some time and rewrite the styling replacing the width px with %s