# How to use multiple media queries in a single CSS file.?

Tags: css

How could i apply different media queries in a single CSS file.I am applying the below queries but only the latest one works..

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
      css styling here
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
     css styling here
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: both should work, do you use !important rules somewhere that overrule the @mediaonly?

Comment: This helps you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#Creating_complex_media_queries

Comment: may this may help you to understand https://stackoverflow.com/a/8792163/2007927

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The meta tag should be added in the `<head>` tag in HTML document. Please check that have you added

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

The sequential order of css code also matters. Please change sequence by following:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
      body{ background:green;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
    body{ background:red;}
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you're defining the same CSS properties of the same elements, the last definition will have priority.

In this case, here is a solution :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
    /* CSS apply on width between 0 and 500px */
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) and (min-width: 501px){
    /* CSS apply on width between 501px and 600px */
}
```

Comment: Why semicolon after 501px?

Comment: Was a mistake (do not seems to be authorized). Post has been edited in this way. Thanks.