# Css: Media Query is not working correctly?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Hi I have a class `Container` so whenever I am trying to give it a `width:1400px` and test on 1900*1080 screen it always pick the wrong media query. i.e. 1200px screen property

```
@media (min-width: 1350px) {
.container {
    width: 1400px;
 }

}

 @media (min-width: 1200px) {
.container {
    width: 1140px;
 }
}
```

I have two media queries for different screens but on the bigger screen it still picks the smallest media query

Comment: Because 1900 is minimum 1200. Minimum means minimum, so everything bigger than 1200 matches it.

Comment: [Why does the order of media queries matter in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790321/why-does-the-order-of-media-queries-matter-in-css)

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the order of the media queries to:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
 .container {
   width: 1140px;
 }
}

@media (min-width: 1350px) {
  .container {
    width: 1400px;
  }
}
```

A screen with at least `1350px` width has also a `width` of at least `1200px`.

So for a screen with `1900px` width both media queries are true, and both `.container` rules are applied, and then the regular rules of CSS are applied, and the last `.container` rule takes precedence.